# Clustering based on predefined shape or variable

Tags: r, leaflet, rgdal, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to use the `clusterOptions`of `leaflet` to cluster my points based on predefined shapes or on a variable. For example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

## Create an example data set ##
data_example <- data.frame(
  Country = c(rep("Italy", 7), rep("France", 7), rep("France", 12), rep("Italy", 9)),
  lon = c(rep(14.25000, 7), rep(2.302732, 7), rep(6.805341, 12), rep(7.327940, 9)),
  lat = c(rep(40.83333, 7), rep(48.809034, 7), rep(45.392361, 12), rep(45.660909, 9)))

## Download the shape files to working directory and load it ##
download.file("http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip" , destfile="TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip")
unzip("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip")
myspdf <- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3")

## The leaflet map ##
leaflet(data_example) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~ lon, lat = ~ lat,
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  setView(6, 44.5, 4) %>%
  addPolygons(data= myspdf)
```

In this example, I want to cluster the points in function of the country using the shape (shape France or shape Italy) or in function of the variable "Country". I searched on the web but I did not find even a beginning of answer. Does anyone have any idea ?